# Why is git showing line endings change although there should be none?

Tags: windows, git, line-endings

I have a file checked in as `CRLF` which should be `CRLF` as can be seen by: `git ls-files --eol`:

```
i/crlf  w/crlf  attr/text eol=crlf      src/Project.Tests/ReadTestsV4.cs
```

But it is still showing a diff with file changes supposedly like this (the real file is `CRLF`):

```
diff --git a/src/Project.Tests/ReadTestsV4.cs b/src/Project.Tests/ReadTestsV4.cs
index 9f139a6..23d11a5 100644
--- a/src/Project.Tests/ReadTestsV4.cs
+++ b/src/Project.Tests/ReadTestsV4.cs
@@ -1,605 +1,605 @@
-^M
-using Renci.SshNet;^M
-using Xunit;^M
-using Project;^M
-using System.Linq;^M
-using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;^M
-using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;^M
...
+
+using Renci.SshNet;
+using Xunit;
+using Project;
+using System.Linq;
+using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
+using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

The gitattributes for this project are:

```
*.json eol=lf
*.cs eol=lf
*.csproj eol=lf
*.scss eol=lf
*.ts eol=lf
*.js eol=lf
*.yml eol=lf
*.md eol=lf
*.xml eol=lf
*.html eol=lf
*.config eol=lf
*.txt eol=lf

*.png binary
*.zip binary

# Except for Testing the SSH Libaray CRLF line endings are required for the tests to succeed
src/Project.Tests/**/*.cs eol=crlf
*.bat eol=crlf
```

My personal git settings are:

```
[alias]
    c = commit -m
    aa = add --all
    s = status 
    slog = log -n 10 --date-order --abbrev-commit --graph --pretty=format:"%h|%an|%ar|%s"
    glog = log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate --branches --all
[user]
    name = Daniel Habenicht
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    editor = \"C:\\MyPath\\bin\\code.cmd\" --wait
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[gpg]
    program = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg.exe
```

I already tried:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

but its always showing theses changes.

Remarks:

- `Project` is a replacement for the real project name which I abbreviated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on here is this:

- The *committed* file (which cannot be changed) actually has CRLF endings.
- The *index copy*, once you run `git add`, will *not* have CRLF endings: it will have LF-only endings.  (It currently has CRLF endings, based on the `git ls-files --eol` output, which makes sense as the initial index copy is made by reading the committed copy into the index.  This keeps the committed copy's CRLF endings intact.  But `eol=crlf` in `.gitattributes` says that when you run `git add`, Git should *strip the carriage returns*, so it will do that.)
- A future commit will be made from what is (in the future) in the index: that is, what *would* be in the index if you run `git add`.
- Therefore the diff between what's committed now, and what would be committed next if you ran `git add` and `git commit`, involves removing all the carriage returns from the file that would be `git add`ed once you run `git add`.

Basically, any time you change the "normalization" process for some file(s)—the way that Git will convert that file or those files from the committed copies to the working tree copies, or vice versa—you may need to make one new "convert the file(s)" commit first.  That way you'll have the new normalization in effect.  You can then make changes the usual way, and these changes will be normalized in accordance with the new normal.

To *make* those newly normalized copies, consider using `git add --renormalize`, if your Git is not too ancient (very old Git versions lack the `--renormalize` option and you must trick such a Git into re-adding the file).  Do this before making any other changes, and make a new commit that has, as its commit message, something that will remind you why you made this commit.  For instance:

```
renormalize files

We changed the `.gitattributes` setting, so we now need to
renormalize files.  Git will show every line changed in
this commit, and `git blame` will point to this commit; use
Git's facilities for skipping over this commit when using
`git blame` because although every line *is* changed, these
changes are purely white-space housekeeping changes that are
not otherwise noteworthy.
```

Now that you have made this new commit so that the *committed* files match the *new normal*, you can go back to working as usual.  If you later are looking for something of interest and run `git blame` and discover this commit and its error message, it will remind you to look up the `git blame` documentation and see how to tell `git blame` *don't count the renormalization commit*.  (See the `--ginore-rev` and `--ignore-revs-file` options.)

Comment: Thanks for answeings that quickly! One follow up question: I can change the Line Endings of the working copy however I like but git still tracks it as change, that is because it still needs to change the index (but this change is not really reflected anywhere), right?

Comment: Pretty much. There are all kinds of nasty little corner cases here, and Git has had a whole series of hacks done to it over the years to try to make it work well, but ultimately it's a messy problem. If you stick with the simple "all lines are CRLF" or "no lines are CRLF" in text files, you'll be OK.

Comment: Are you a git developer? I've made an reproduction because this problem actually leads to some other problems: https://github.com/DanielHabenicht/bug-reproduction.git-repo/blob/main/README.md
I will file a bug report as it is really unexpected.

Comment: I've contributed some tiny things to the Git project but I'm not a major Git developer. I *am* pretty convinced that crlf editing is a bad idea overall, but that's a completely different topic...